# Proving finite amount of 'non-cool' numbers

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, induction

We will call a natural number $n \in \mathbb{N}$ **'cool'** if two natural numbers $t,k \in \mathbb{N}$ exist such that $n = 4t + 7k$
For example: 8 and 26 are cool because:
$ 4 \cdot 2 + 7 \cdot 0 = 8$
and
$4 \cdot 3 + 7 \cdot 2 = 26$

Q: Prove there is a finite amount of **Non-cool** natural numbers.

I thought about finding a natural number $N$ so that for all $n \geq N$ is 'cool', and to prove that with complete(strong) induction, however I a don't know how to continue from here..

Thank you!

Comment: See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem

Comment: @richrow that is so cool!! thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We show that every number from $35$ onwards is cool. We simply consider $n-4t$ for $1 \leqslant t \leqslant 7$. As $4t$ leaves distinct remainders for each $t$, $n-4t$ will also leave distinct remainders when divided by $7$. As there are only $7$ possible remainders, one of these is divisible by $7$. Then, $n-4t=7k \implies n = 4t+7k$. Furthermore, we are guaranteed that $k$ is also a positive integer as $n-4t \geqslant n-4(7) \geqslant 35-28 \geqslant 7$.

Comment: But isn't the frobenius number for 4 and 7 is 17 ?

Comment: Yes it is. But note that you wanted $k$ and $t$ to be natural, not whole numbers, so you don't include $0$. For example, $20>17$ is not cool, but is greater than the Frobenius number.

Comment: @Haran: I don’t know about the OP, but for many of us the natural numbers include $0$ and the whole numbers do not, if we even use the term at all — I tend to think of it as a grade school term.

Comment: Note that different authors do or don't include zero as an element of the natural numbers.  The author of the original question that OP asks clearly includes zero as noted by the included example of $4\cdot 2 + 7\cdot \color{red}{0}=8$ being "cool."

Comment: We consider 0 to be natural

Comment: So $0 \in \mathbb{N}$? Hmm... Anyways, it doesn't matter. I never said that $35$ is the smallest number from which every number is cool. I just wanted to give a simple argument for OP. $35$ avoids all confusion by not including $0$ just in case...

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think I did not quite understood it, is it a proof by induction(strong) ? thank you!

Comment: @Remember1312 Do you know modular congruences, like mod $7$ and stuff?

Comment: @Haran No it is a discrete mathematics question (very early university- year 1)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108260/discussion-between-remember1312-and-haran).

Comment: But why do you pick 35 ? how does this shows there are finite amount of non cool numbers? I mean, why not choose 17 ? or 3 or 5 ?

Comment: By choosing $n=35$, I have $n-4t \geqslant n-4(7)=n-28 \geqslant 35-28>0$. This wouldn't work if I chose $n=3$ or $n=5$. Moreover, if all the numbers from $35$ onwards are cool, only the positive integers less than $35$ can be non-cool. Clearly, there are only finitely many such positive integers. The set of non-cool numbers is a subset of them, and will thus also be finite in size.